# PowerShell regex, count groups instances and use it as reference in the same regex

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-group

I am trying to write a powershell regex where is two groups "Dates" and "Hours" and I need these two to appear the same time.
This is where I am now

```
(\d{8}-\d{8})((?<Dates>,\d{8}-\d{8})*)(\|)(\d\d:\d\d-\d\d:\d\d)(?<Hours>,\d\d:\d\d-\d\d:\d\d){0,}
```

It need to match the first four but not the two last one.

```
20210701-20210718,20210801-20210814|18:00-07:00,12:00-13:00
20210701-20210718|18:00-07:00
20210701-20210718,20210801-20210814|18:00-07:00,12:00-13:00
20210701-20210718,20210801-20210814,20210801-20210814|18:00-07:00,12:00-13:00,12:00-13:00
20210701-20210718,20210801-20210814|18:00-07:00,12:00-13:00,12:00-13:00
20210701-20210718,20210801-20210814,20210801-20210814|18:00-07:00,12:00-13:00
```

I tried to change the last {0,} to $Dates, $(Dates) combinations with .Length etc.
But could find anything on google.

If you have an idea please let me know. Thanks

Comment: This is only matches for one group. The point is it should match to any number of groups but with the same value on the left and right of the "|"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powershell regex is .NET powered, so you can use the *balanced constructs*:

```cs
^(?<t>,?(?<Dates>\d{8}-\d{8}))+\|(?<-t>,?(?<Hours>\d\d:\d\d-\d\d:\d\d))+\r?$(?(t)(?!))
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3ct%3e%2c%3f%28%3f%3cDates%3e%5cd%7b8%7d-%5cd%7b8%7d%29%29%2b%5c%7c%28%3f%3c-t%3e%2c%3f%28%3f%3cHours%3e%5cd%5cd%3a%5cd%5cd-%5cd%5cd%3a%5cd%5cd%29%29%2b%5cr%3f%24%28%3f%28t%29%28%3f!%29%29&i=20210701-20210718%2c20210801-20210814%7c18%3a00-07%3a00%2c12%3a00-13%3a00%0d%0a20210701-20210718%7c18%3a00-07%3a00%0d%0a20210701-20210718%2c20210801-20210814%7c18%3a00-07%3a00%2c12%3a00-13%3a00%0d%0a20210701-20210718%2c20210801-20210814%2c20210801-20210814%7c18%3a00-07%3a00%2c12%3a00-13%3a00%2c12%3a00-13%3a00%0d%0a20210701-20210718%2c20210801-20210814%7c18%3a00-07%3a00%2c12%3a00-13%3a00%2c12%3a00-13%3a00%0d%0a20210701-20210718%2c20210801-20210814%2c20210801-20210814%7c18%3a00-07%3a00%2c12%3a00-13%3a00&o=m) (note the `\r?` is only needed with the `(?m)` flag).

**NOTE**: If there should be NO comma at the start of string and right after `|`, you need to adjust the `,?` pattern by restricting the left-hand side context:

```cs
^(?<t>(?:(?<!^),)?(?<Dates>\d{8}-\d{8}))+\|(?<-t>(?:(?<!\|),)?(?<Hours>\d\d:\d\d-\d\d:\d\d))+\r?$(?(t)(?!))
```

See [this .NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3Ct%3E%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3C!%5E%29%2C%29%3F%28%3F%3CDates%3E%5Cd%7B8%7D-%5Cd%7B8%7D%29%29%2B%5C%7C%28%3F%3C-t%3E%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3C!%5C%7C%29%2C%29%3F%28%3F%3CHours%3E%5Cd%5Cd%3A%5Cd%5Cd-%5Cd%5Cd%3A%5Cd%5Cd%29%29%2B%5Cr%3F%24%28%3F%28t%29%28%3F!%29%29&i=20210701-20210718%2C20210801-20210814%7C18%3A00-07%3A00%2C12%3A00-13%3A00%0D%0A20210701-20210718%7C18%3A00-07%3A00%0D%0A%2C20210701-20210718%7C18%3A00-07%3A00%0D%0A20210701-20210718%7C%2C18%3A00-07%3A00%0D%0A20210701-20210718%2C20210801-20210814%7C18%3A00-07%3A00%2C12%3A00-13%3A00%0D%0A20210701-20210718%2C20210801-20210814%2C20210801-20210814%7C18%3A00-07%3A00%2C12%3A00-13%3A00%2C12%3A00-13%3A00%0D%0A20210701-20210718%2C20210801-20210814%7C18%3A00-07%3A00%2C12%3A00-13%3A00%2C12%3A00-13%3A00%0D%0A20210701-20210718%2C20210801-20210814%2C20210801-20210814%7C18%3A00-07%3A00%2C12%3A00-13%3A00&o=m) where `(?:(?<!^),)?` matches an optional comma only if it does not occur at the start of string and  the `(?:(?<!\|),)?` matches an optional comma if it is not immediately preceded with a pipe char.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - a non-capturing group matching

  - `(?<t>,?(?<Dates>\d{8}-\d{8}))+` - one or more occurrences of an optional `,` and then eight digits, `-`, eight digits captured into the `Dates` group (and a value is pushed on to the Group "t" stack)
  - `\|`  - a `|` char
  - `(?<-t>,?(?<Hours>\d\d:\d\d-\d\d:\d\d))+` - one or more occurrences of an optional `,` and then two digits, `:`, two digits, `:` and again two digits captured into the `Hours` group (and a value is popped from the Group "t" stack)
- `\r?$` (or `$` if the strings are tested standalone) - end of a line/string
- `(?(t)(?!))` - a conditional: if Group "t" capture stack is not empty, fail the match.

Powershell test:

[image]

Comment: That is a really great approach! ++

Comment: It is a bit hard for me to understand. but nice description I will figure out something about it. Unfortunately runs to an error.
t : The term 't' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Okay so you basicli add to the <t> group and than substract from it. And check if it is 0.

Comment: I think before the last t you need to put a $ sign. Now it have some problem with the ?!

Comment: @David You are right the regex checks the number of captures in the `t` group, at the start, the first pattern adds up values, and then the second part after `|` decreases the number, and the last conditional checks if the stack is empty. No need to add any more `$` anchors here.

Comment: @David I posted the screenshot proving this regex works as intended.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am so sorry you are rigth. I used double quotes instead of single ones. All is working right now.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a regex centered question, but since PowerShell is tagged and has the capability to use other operators for grouping and comparison, you may do the following:

```
Get-Content file.txt | Foreach-Object {
    $row = $_
    $date,$time = $row -split '\|'
    if ($date.Split(',').Count -eq $time.Split(',').Count) {
        $row
    }
}
```

This does assume that your lines only contain dates and times. If there are other lines, you will need to intermingle regex to pattern match.

Comment: By that logic you could just do `Get-Content file.txt | Where { $_.split('|')[0].Split(',').count -eq $_.split('|')[1].Split(',').count }`